# Determinant Algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

We want to calculate the following determinant $$A(n,k)=\begin{vmatrix} \binom{n}{0} & \binom{n}{1}& \cdots & \binom{n}{k}\\ \binom{n+1}{0} & \binom{n+1}{1}& \cdots & \binom{n+1}{k}\\ \vdots & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots \\ \binom{n+k}{0} & \binom{n+k}{1}& \cdots & \binom{n+k}{k} \end{vmatrix}$$

I observed that the matrix is a square matrix of order $k+1$ and every element $a_{i,j}$ is of the form $$a_{i,j}=\binom{n+i-1}{j-1}$$ and tried applying the identity $$\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-1}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$ by subtracting row $n-1$ from row $n$, row $n-2$ from row $n-1$ etc. and noting that the first column consists entirely of $1$'s, the next column is $n+i-1$, where $i$ is the number of each row. I tried factorising a common factor, but didn't get much further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show an explicit example: $A(n,3)$.

$$A(n,3)=\begin{vmatrix} \binom{n}{0} & \binom{n}{1}& \binom n2& \binom{n}{3}\\ \binom{n+1}{0} & \binom{n+1}{1}& \binom{n+1}{2} & \binom{n+1}{3}\\ \binom{n+2}{0} & \binom{n+2}{1}& \binom{n+2}{2} & \binom{n+2}{3}\\ \binom{n+3}{0} & \binom{n+3}{1}& \binom{n+3}{2} & \binom{n+3}{3} \end{vmatrix}$$

Using your idea:

$$A(n,3)=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & \binom{n}{1}& \binom n2& \binom{n}{3}\\ 0 & \binom{n}{0}& \binom{n}{1} & \binom{n}{2}\\ 0 & \binom{n+1}{0}& \binom{n+1}{1} & \binom{n+1}{2}\\ 0 & \binom{n+2}{0}& \binom{n+2}{1} & \binom{n+2}{2} \end{vmatrix}$$

Using cofactor expansion:

$$A(n,3)=\begin{vmatrix} \binom{n}{0}& \binom{n}{1} & \binom{n}{2}\\ \binom{n+1}{0}& \binom{n+1}{1} & \binom{n+1}{2}\\ \binom{n+2}{0}& \binom{n+2}{1} & \binom{n+2}{2} \end{vmatrix}$$

Do you see a pattern?

Comment: That's $A(n,2)$, I was looking for this recursion. Thank you! Cheers!