# Determinant of matrix of binomial coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, binomial-coefficients, determinant

My homework is to calculate the determinant of the matrix:
$$
\det(A) = \begin{vmatrix} \binom{n}{0} & \binom{n}{1} & \cdots & \binom{n}{r} \\\ \binom{n+1}{0} & \binom{n+1}{1} & \cdots & \binom{n+1}{r} \\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\ \binom{n+r}{0} & \binom{n+r}{1} & \cdots & \binom{n+r}{r}  \end{vmatrix} = D(r,n)
$$
and following is my proof:

Using the identity $\binom{m}{k} + \binom{m}{k+1} = \binom{k+1}{m+1}$, then after transforming A by a sequence of operators on rows
$$
L_{r+1} \leftarrow L_{r+1} - L_{r}, \:  L_{r} \leftarrow L_{r} - L_{r-1}, \dots, \: L_2 \leftarrow L_2 - L_1
$$
(the last row is affected first, then the second row...)

we have
$$
\begin{vmatrix} \binom{n}{0} & \binom{n}{1} & \cdots & \binom{n}{r} \\\ \binom{n+1}{0} & \binom{n+1}{1} & \cdots & \binom{n+1}{r} \\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\ \binom{n+r}{0} & \binom{n+r}{1} & \cdots & \binom{n+r}{r}  \end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix} \binom{n}{0} & \binom{n}{1} & \cdots & \binom{n}{r} \\\ 0 & \binom{n}{0} & \cdots & \binom{n}{r-1} \\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\ 0 & \binom{n+r-1}{0} & \cdots & \binom{n+r-1}{r-1}  \end{vmatrix} = \binom{n}{0} \begin{vmatrix} \binom{n}{0} & \cdots & \binom{n}{r-1} \\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\ \binom{n+r-1}{0} & \cdots & \binom{n+r-1}{r-1}  \end{vmatrix}
$$
Or
$$
D(r,n) = D(r-1,n-1)
$$
By recurrence
$$
D(r,n) = D(0,n-r) = \binom{n-r}{0} = 1
$$
The grader gave me simply "Wrong" as the feedback but I still cannot find where the error is.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sounds like you should talk to the professor

Comment: It believe it is $D(r,n) = D(r-1,n)$ instead of $D(r-1,n-1)$ but it does not change the final result as $D(0,n)=1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determinant Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3867182/determinant-algorithm)

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I know how to calculate it, but I don't understand why the grader put simply "Wrong" (I've got zero point for this) without further explain. I think the mistake is the one revealed by @Lelouch.

Comment: Indeed, I saw that comment, and you can compare what you wrote with the answer in the link. (Actually, my question was generated automatically when I voted to close as a duplicate with this link, but I would rather have formulated like "This answers your question".)